# Regarding dynamically updating table view upon form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, post

I'm using `rails` 4.2.7.1, `ruby` 2.3.1. I have a landing page containing an add button which upon clicking pops up a new window (in a new `URL`). This new window has a form in it. I want the landing page to have a table which is dynamically populated every time the form on the pop-up is submitted (basically re-direct back to the landing page and update the table).

We've an internal framework for creating `HTML` views as `ruby` objects (for instance, a table object or a panel object). These are created within the `model` class and have methods to enable their rendering (essentially use `content_tag` within the `ActionView Helper` to render the final `HTML` from `.erb/HAML`).

Now, the problem is the `controller` always ends up calling these methods in the `model` class every time the page is loaded. Due to this the objects aren't retaining their previous values. I got around this by using class variables but is there a better way to handle this? I haven't explored `rails caching` yet.

I'd be open to listening to solutions which don't follow the model described above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> We've an internal framework for creating HTML views as ruby objects
>   (for instance, a table object or a panel object). These are created
>   within the model class and have methods to enable their rendering
>   (essentially use content_tag within the ActionView Helper to render
>   the final HTML from .erb/HAML).

I don't want to sound rude, but why?  This seems like a huge over-complication and source of errors.

Anyway,

You'll want to look into Websockets.  If you can upgrade to Rails 5, ActionCable might be the answer.  Otherwise you could have the view update with a simple `setInterval`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into Websockets and setInterval. Rails 5 isn't an option. Framework is for common look and feel across apps I believe.

Comment: @linuxNoob As a note actioncable was a stand alone library prior to rails consuming it (rails 5) there are other tutorials out there for implementation onto rail 4 but here's one for edification http://khalsa.guru/posts/17. Also models having any knowledge of UI seems like a tight coupling design flaw maybe see if you can correct this before it gets out of control (if it hasn't already)

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks, I will look into that. I don't think I have the control to change the design since the format being followed is very set here plus I'm new to web dev to be questioning such large scale decisions.